# What exactly does adjustViewBounds do for the image output?

Tags: android, imageview

I have this code:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:src="@drawable/house1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

and I have this code:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:src="@drawable/house1"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" 
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

But I do not see any changes in output of the image.

What exactly does adjustViewBounds do for the image output?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When using `adjustViewBounds`, you need to set either width or height of your ImageView to `wrap_content` and the other to a fixed value. Then when you set `adjustViewBounds` to `true`, Android adjusts your image based on the fixed height or width value you've set and keeps aspect ratio. The `scaleType` also plays a role.